# Командная строка

Tags: c++, visual-c++

В командной строке задается признак фигуры, объем которой необходимо вычислить:

s – шар (аргумент – радиус);

k – куб (аргумент – сторона);

p – параллелепипед (аргументы – стороны a, b и c)

c – цилиндр (аргументы – радиус основания и высота).

Вычислить объем соответствующей фигуры. Обращение к функциям реализуется через указатель.

Это то, что у меня есть.

Код компилируется без ошибок, но ничего не приходит консоль.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
double pi = 3.14;

double sphere(double r)
{
    return (4 * pi * pow(r,3))/3;
}

double cube(double s)
{
    return pow(s,3);
}

double parallelepiped(double a, double b, double c)
{
    return a * b * c;
}

double cylinder(double r, double h)
{
    return pi * pow(r, 2) * h;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double (*psphere)(double r) = &sphere;
    double (*pcube)(double s) = &cube;
    double (*pparallelepiped)(double a, double b, double c) = &parallelepiped;
    double (*pcylinder)(double r, double h) = &cylinder;

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        if (!strcmp(argv[1], "s"))
        {
            if(argc == 3) {
                cout << " Volume of the sphere: " << psphere(atoi(argv[2])) << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "k"))
        {
            if (argc == 3)
            {
                cout << " Volume of the cube: " << pcube(atoi(argv[2])) << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "p"))
        {
            if (argc == 5)
            {
                 cout << "Volume of the parallelepiped: " <<  parallelepiped(atoi(argv[2]),atoi(argv[3]),atoi(argv[4])) << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "c"))
        {
            if (argc == 4)
            {
                cout << " Volume of the cylinder: " << pcylinder(atoi(argv[2]),atoi(argv[3])) << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    _getch();
}
```

Comment: Вы забыли сам вопрос написать. Просто вывалить код и написать изначальную задачу - недостаточно. Опииште, что именно в вашем коде не работает или работает не так, как нужно.

Comment: в чем суть вопроса?

Comment: Код страшный, но на вскидку должен работать. Если исправите косяк в проверке аргументов куба и параллелепипеда. А за одно правильно отпарсите ввод - atoi выдаст целое, а не double.

Comment: Минус за заголовок.

Answer (score 1):

У параллелепипеда и куба перепутаны проверки на число аргументов.

Comment: можно показать как правильно?

Comment: @Nas_04, 3 и 5 в этих ветвях переставь.

Comment: Я сделал, но все тот же.

Comment: @Nas_04, ну так дебажь...